# does libGDX box2dDebugRenderer renders ray?

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, physics

I am using `libGDX` for hobby Game Development,I am using two stages one is for graphics and one is for `box2d world` with `debugDraw`, every box2d fixtures `debugDraw` well with their graphics but I cant `debugDraw` a raycast!, how can I easily achieve that?
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DebugDraw does not render RayCasts as they are not an object in the box2d world. It is more like a query and does not persist.

But you could use your starting vector and the the point of the [RayCastCallback](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/RayCastCallback.html) that is going stop the raycast to draw a line via [DebugRenderer.line(a, b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835062/libgdx-draw-line). Of course, if you want this line to show up more than one frame you have to store your vectors somewhere.