# Libgdx circle with linewidth

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I've started using libgdx and am trying to simply make a circle with a pretty thick stroke. As of yet I have not found anyway to make a stroke at all. `pixmap.setStrokeWidth()` is even in the API but appears to have been removed (?), and `Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(width);` has no effect. How can I just change the stroke of the line?
Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    pixmap = new Pixmap(2 * w, 2 * w, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    pixmap.drawCircle(w, w, w);
    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();

    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    sprite.setPosition(-w / 2, -w);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Random shot: What's the default color of a Pixmap? Could it be the code's drawing black on black onto the Pixmap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenGL "line width" API is lame.  The standard only requires that width 1.0 is supported, so many implementations (especially in mobile devices) do not support more than that.  See [Libgdx gl10.glLineWidth()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680908/libgdx-gl10-gllinewidth?rq=1).

You might try drawing two filled discs, both with the same center.  The second one should have a smaller radius and should be drawn to the Pixmap in such a way to set the alpha to 0 where its drawn.  That should leave a "fat" circle.